# What is the difference between using apache sqoop installed in Apache Hadoop and Cloudera Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, sqoop

Why does Apache Sqoop recommends to use Cloudera Hadoop instead of Apache Hadoop?

Is there any performance related issues ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloudera distribution of Sqoop match the Apache Sqoop version. There shall be no major performance related issues. There is however benefit in running Cloudera distribution of Sqoop on CDH as you get nice packaging and easy installation for free.

Jarcec

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop has a single functionality of transfer of data between Hadoop and relational databases or mainframes, so theres no such difference between cloudera and apache hadoop. Though the configuration is quite easy in cloudera as its just a matter of clicks and cloudera provides a managed service for hadoop if opted for cloudera enterprise edition.